# Extension method for list that performs arithmetic operation on list item

Tags: c#

I would like to write an extension method on a list that performs artithmetic operation on the list item and a supplied double and then writes the result back into the list. Example:

```
public class Datum
{
    public DateTime DateTime;
    public double Value;
}
public static class DateExt
{
    public static double Average(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this)
    {
        return @this.Average(datum => datum.Value);
    }

    public static double Sum(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this)
    {
        return @this.Sum(datum => datum.Value);
    }


    public static IEnumerable<Datum> InTimeRange(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return from datum in @this
               where (start <= datum.DateTime && datum.DateTime < end)  
               select datum;
    }
}
```

This lets me do the following:

```
return somelist.InTimeRange(startdate, enddate).Sum()
```

which would return the sum over all items between the two dates.
I would now like to create an extension method that takes a double and updates the list accordingly. For instance:

```
return somelist.InTimeRange(startdate, enddate).Addition(double val)
```

should add val to each item in the list that is between start date and end date. I tried this:

```
  public static double Addition(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, double val)
    {
        return @this.(datum => datum.Value)+= val;
    }
```

But this doesnt work.

So if list Item is 10 and val = 5 the updated list item in same position should be 15 - just for the avoidance of doubt.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why it does not work? What's the error message or what it behaves like so you think it is incorrect? Other than that - your code looks incorrect in the first place - `@this.(datum...)` what is it supposed to mean? You don't call any method

Comment: You say it "doesn't work".  Does it fail to do what you expect it to, or does it throw an exception or does it just silently fail?

Comment: it says Identifier expected.

Comment: What is the value returned by `Addition()` supposed to be?

Comment: @MatthewWatson OP says an updated list "so if list item is 10 and val = 5 *the updated list item in the same position should be 15*"

Comment: @BobVale In which case I think your answer is correct (+1ed already)

Comment: @npvh I've answered for both cases but can you clarify is the solution supposed to modify the existing list or provide a modified copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say update the collection so I'm assuming this is a destructive operation (i.e. it modifies the input)

```
public static IEnumerable<Datum> Addition(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, double val) {
     foreach (var datum in @this) {
        datum.Value += val;
     }
     return @this;
 }
```

Alternatively for a non destructive version

```
public static IEnumerable<Datum> Addition(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, double val) {
     return from datum in @this
            select new Datum {
                 DateTime = datum.DateTime,
                 Value = datum.Value + val
            };
 }
```

Comment: Either that or he wants to return the accumulation (having added `val` to everything).

Comment: @MatthewWatson which would could be answered using `Sum()` afterwards eg `list.Addition(5).Sum()`

Comment: Thanks. I think that does the job. How do you think this is going to be performance wise, if I have to do this multiple times over a long list? THanks again

Comment: @npvh I'm not sure that the `Addition` method could be the performance problem.  Its the `InTimeRange` method that will be the issue as it will iterate the entire list.  You may wish to consider using a SortedList on the date field with a binary search to establish the start and end indexes

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a more Generic version of it which accepts an `Action`?

```
list.Do(d => d.Value += 1000);
```

---

```
public static partial class  Extensions
{
    public static void Do<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach(var item in e)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to that, I was about to add a more generic solution to my answer!